# Simple Pivot Table Transposition in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite

I'm trying really hard to understand how to use the pivot operator to transpose a table but I can't figure it out. Any help would be great. Here is my query that I need to transpose.

```
SELECT 
    sum(delayCarrier>0)  AS 'Carrier Delay',
    sum(delayWeather>0) AS 'Weather Delay',
    sum(delayTraffic>0) AS 'Air Traffic Delay',
    sum(delaySecurity>0)  AS 'Security Delay'
FROM flights
```

And here is the table version.
[image]

I need it to read:

```
'TypeOfDelay','Frequency'
-------------------------
Carrier Delay | 32093
Weather Delay | 4887
Air Traffic Delay | 40730
Security Delay | 215
```

Sorry I know this question has been asked a lot and I've looked at many of them but I just can't seem to gain any intuition. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a query which will give you the output you want, although I can't honestly say that it is a pivot, or that it is pretty.

```
SELECT 'Carrier Delay' AS TypeOfDelay, SUM(delayCarrier > 0) AS Frequency
FROM flights
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Weather Delay' AS TypeOfDelay, SUM(delayWeather > 0) AS Frequency
FROM flights
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Air Traffic Delay' AS TypeOfDelay, SUM(delayTraffic > 0) AS Frequency
FROM flights
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Security Delay' AS TypeOfDelay, SUM(delaySecurity > 0) AS Frequency
FROM flights
```